# I have two machine.config files on my server, which one do I edit and how do I verify they are being used?

Tags: .net, asp.net, windows-server-2003, machine.config

I need to do some performance tuning and need to modify the following settings: [processModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1%28VS.71%29.aspx), [httpRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), and [connectionManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903351%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). Simple enough I suppose, but I'm not sure which of the two machine.config files to edit, or do I edit both?

- \Windows\microsoft.net\ **Framework** \v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config
- \Windows\microsoft.net\ **Framework64** \v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config

As a follow up question, how do I verify that the settings have been applied?

I should mention that the server is running Windows Server 2003 Enterprise (64-bit) with IIS 6.0 (64-bit) and MSSQL Server Enterprise 2005 (64-bit).

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The one located in Framework64 is being used if your .net application/IIS is running in 64 bit mode. The other is used if running in 32 bit mode.

When bringing up the Windows Task Manager, if there's "*32" appended to the process name, then it runs in 32 bit. If not it runs under 64 bit.

If your OS is 64bit that is, something I assume since you have both folders on your machine.

If you are using IIS6/7, the process is named w3wp.exe.

IIS7 has more settings for this as well which can be read [at this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rakkimk/iis7-running-32-bit-and-64-bit-asp-net-versions-at-the-same-time-on-different-worker-processes).

Comment: Looking at the Task Manager right now, I see "w3wp.exe". So does that mean I'm running IIS 7.0 and not 6.0 as I had thought? I also see "sqlservr.exe". Both processes do not have the "*32" suffix. 

However, I do see other procs that do have the "*32" suffix (i.e., "sqlbrowser.exe *32", "SqlWb.exe *32"). Any idea what that means?

Comment: By the way, I was using this article to determine which version of IIS is installed by default with Windows Server 2003: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224609

Comment: Both IIS6 and 7 are named w3wp. I edited this in my answer. And if w3wp is missing *32, they are running in 64 bit, and you should edit the machine.config in Framework64.

Comment: Thanks Mikael! Ultimately, you answered my question my first question. Would you happen to be able to answer the second? Or do I trust that these settings are being used?

Comment: You should trust them, but connectionManagement should be easily tested by trying to open more than the specified number of connections to a host.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would edit neither, but instead modify the web.config files at site or application level.

You should be able to modify `httpRuntime` and `connectionManagement` settings in this way, but not `processModel`, which can only be used in machine.config.

However you [may not need to modify processModel](https://web.archive.org/web/20170506002052/http://www.microsoft.com:80/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/ee81b97b-b967-48f7-8ce9-1796a2e994fd.mspx?mfr=true) if you are on Windows Server 2003.

As others have pointed out, if you do want to modify machine.config, IIS6 will run in 64-bit mode by default, so that's the version to edit.  If you need to run in 32-bit mode (e.g. because you need to use 32-bit native DLLs), you can configure 32-bit mode as follows:

```
cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 "true"
```

See [this TechNet article](https://web.archive.org/web/20161023052804/http://www.microsoft.com:80/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0aafb9a0-1b1c-4a39-ac9a-994adc902485.mspx?mfr=true) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Joe. I will be using web.config for all the above settings.

Comment: unless you want the settings to apply server-wide(for all sites). Then Machine.config is the appropriate location.

Comment: "unless you want the settings to apply server-wide(for all sites). Then Machine.config is the appropriate location. " - I'd still argue that putting it in the web.config of each site is better.  Then the sites are self-contained, and you can move them to a different server without wondering why they suddenly stop working.

Comment: @joe I realize this is a super old comment, but sudden breaking if the app is moved across servers is exactly what I want to happen.

Comment: @asawyer "breaking if the app is moved across servers is exactly what I want to happen" - not sure why you'd want that, but it's easy to achieve: e.g. just have an appSetting with the server name; when you start up compare it with Environment.MachineName and start ringing alarm bells if they don't match.