# How do I check the changes in machine.config file are consumed by the IIS?

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure, iis, machine.config

I have added some params in machine.config file in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config.

```
<system.net>
     <connectionManagement>
         <add address="*" maxconnection="24" />
     </connectionManagement>
 </system.net>
 <system.web>
     <processModel autoConfig="true"
         maxWorkerThreads = "100"
         maxIoThreads = "100"
         minWorkerThreads = "50"
         minIoThreads = "50"
     />
     <httpRuntime 
         minFreeThreads="176" 
         minLocalRequestFreeThreads="152" 
     />
 </system.web>
```

How do I check if the changes have been affected in the IIS?

Comment: Note that you only changed the 32 bit file, which won’t apply to any 64 bit process.

Answer (score 0):

> Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config: Holds the global defaults for the .NET framework settings, including some of the ASP.NET ones (the rest of the settings are in the web.config at the same folder, which is sometimes called the root web.config).

`ConnectionManagement` should be easily tested by trying to open more than the specified number of connections to a host. For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257015/i-have-two-machine-config-files-on-my-server-which-one-do-i-edit-and-how-do-i-v).